# Updating a scala case class

Tags: scala, scalaz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update operations on a Scala Case Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438277/update-operations-on-a-scala-case-class)

This question came to me this evening.

I have two instantiated case classes of the same type.

```
case class Foo(a : Option[String], b : Option[String], c : Option[String])
```

Lets call the instantiated classes A and B.

```
val a = Foo(a=Some("foo"), b=Some("bar"), c=Some("baz"))
val b = Foo(a=None, b=Some("etch"), c=None)
```

I'm wondering if its possible to update case class A with B in a single operation in a generic way.

```
val c = b *oper* a // Foo(a=Some("foo"), b=Some("etch"), c=Some("baz"))
```

with parameters that are set as None ignored. Ideally the operation should also be generic so it can act on any type of case class.

I have some intuition that it might be possible to do this with Scalaz by converting the class into a tuple/list first and converting back to a class after the operation is complete - perhaps using the ApplicativeBuilder? Any ideas?

Comment: `A` and `B` are not called classes, but instances or objects.

Comment: There is something wrong with code. The attributes a and c are String or Option[String] ?

Answer (score 4):

```
case class Foo(a:Option[String], b:Option[String], c:Option[String])

val a = Foo(a=Some("foo"), b=Some("bar"), c=Some("baz"))
val b = Foo(a=None, b=Some("etch"), c=None)

def op(a:Foo, b:Foo) = Foo(b.a.orElse(a.a), b.b.orElse(a.b), b.c.orElse(a.c))

op(a,b)
```

If I understand you correctly......

Comment: Renaming the arguments in the `op` to something like l and r would make the code more readable.

Comment: This is intentional :) , using the same nomenclature as in the question!