# Update operations on a Scala Case Class

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have two instantiated case classes of the same type.

```
case class Foo(x : Option[String], y : Option[String], z : Option[String])
```

Lets call the instantiated classes A and B.

```
val a = Foo(x=Some("foo"), y=Some("bar"), z=Some("baz"))
val b = Foo(x=None, y=Some("etch"), z=None)
```

I'm wondering if its possible to update case class A with B in a single operation in a generic way.

```
val c = b *oper* a // produces Foo(x=Some("foo"), y=Some("etch"), z=Some("baz"))
```

with parameters that are set as None ignored. Ideally the operation should also be generic so it can act on any type of case class.

I have some intuition that it might be possible to do this with Scalaz by converting the class into a tuple/list first and converting back to a class after the operation is complete - perhaps using the ApplicativeBuilder? Am I thinking about this in the right way? Any ideas?

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm sorry? What exactly doesn't compile? The code snippet? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a scala case class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430109/updating-a-scala-case-class)

Comment: @Rasputin Jones: You're not only using `a` and `b` both as variable names and named arguments, but also pass a `String` where a `Option[String]` is expected. This will confuse especially beginners.

Comment: The variable names are not as problematic as the wrong types. The latter will not compile. See my edit...

Comment: @missingfaktor: What is the difference between the two questions? Both are one and the same.

Comment: @Antoras, my bad. Retracted the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Antoras. @Jorg, yes it's a duplicate question. Some perps voted my initial question down and provided a low quality answer. If enough of us flag it the question will be deleted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Fairly straightforward Scalaz solution (not very general)

You can use a semigroup instance to wrap up a lot of the details:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

case class Foo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String])

implicit object fooSemigroup extends Semigroup[Foo] {
  def fromFoo(f: Foo) = (f.a.fst, f.b.fst, f.c.fst)
  def toFoo(t: (FirstOption[String], FirstOption[String], FirstOption[String])) =
    Foo(t._1.value, t._2.value, t._3.value)
  def append(x: Foo, y: => Foo) = toFoo(fromFoo(x) |+| fromFoo(y))
}
```

Which gives us:

```
scala> val a = Foo(Some("foo"), Some("bar"), Some("baz"))
a: Foo = Foo(Some(foo),Some(bar),Some(baz))

scala> val b = Foo(None, Some("etch"), None)
b: Foo = Foo(None,Some(etch),None)

scala> b |+| a
res11: Foo = Foo(Some(foo),Some(etch),Some(baz))
```

Which I think is what you want, although it's not very general.

---

### Scalaz + Shapeless solution

If you want something that works for all case classes (given the appropriate type class instances for members), you can use the following combination of [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/) and Scalaz. Note that I'm drawing on [missingfactor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11446109/334519) and [this example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala) by Miles Sabin. First for some monoid instances:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import shapeless._, HList._

implicit object hnilMonoid extends Monoid[HNil] {
  val zero = HNil
  def append(a: HNil, b: => HNil) = HNil
}

implicit def hlistMonoid[H, T <: HList](
  implicit mh: Monoid[H],
  mt: Monoid[T]
): Monoid[H :: T] = new Monoid[H :: T] {
  val zero = mh.zero :: mt.zero
  def append(a: H :: T, b: => H :: T) =
    (a.head |+| b.head) :: (a.tail |+| b.tail)
}

implicit def caseClassMonoid[C, L <: HList](
  implicit iso: Iso[C, L],
  ml: Monoid[L]
) = new Monoid[C] {
  val zero = iso.from(ml.zero)
  def append(a: C, b: => C) = iso.from(iso.to(a) |+| iso.to(b))
}
```

Next for the sake of simplicitly I'm just going to put the "First" monoid instance for `Option` in scope, instead of using the `FirstOption` wrapper as I did above.

```
implicit def optionFirstMonoid[A] = new Monoid[Option[A]] {
  val zero = None
  def append(a: Option[A], b: => Option[A]) = a orElse b
}
```

Now for our case class:

```
case class Foo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String])
```

And the `Iso` instance to convert it to an `HList` and back:

```
implicit def fooIso = Iso.hlist(Foo.apply _, Foo.unapply _)
```

And we're done:

```
scala> val a = Foo(Some("foo"), Some("bar"), Some("baz"))
a: Foo = Foo(Some(foo),Some(bar),Some(baz))

scala> val b = Foo(None, Some("etch"), None)
b: Foo = Foo(None,Some(etch),None)

scala> b |+| a
res0: Foo = Foo(Some(foo),Some(etch),Some(baz))
```

You could use semigroups instead of monoids here as well and save a few lines, but I was trying to get away with as much copying and pasting from the `shapeless/examples` code as possible, so I'll leave that as an exercise.

---

### Performance

To address your comment about performance, here's a completely unscientific benchmark of the latter solution versus a standard library solution using `orElse` (Scala 2.9.2, IcedTea7 2.2.1):

```
def add(x: Foo, y: Foo) = Foo(x.a orElse y.a, x.b orElse y.b, x.c orElse y.c)

def ros = if (util.Random.nextBoolean)
  Some(util.Random.nextString(util.Random.nextInt(10))) else None

val foos = Seq.fill(500000)(Foo(ros, ros, ros))

def time(block: => Unit) = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  (block, System.currentTimeMillis - start)
}
```

And then after running each a couple of dozen times:

```
scala> Iterator.fill(10)(time(foos.reduce(add(_, _)))._2).sum / 10
res4: Long = 49

scala> Iterator.fill(10)(time(foos.reduce(_ |+| _))._2).sum / 10
res5: Long = 265
```

Somewhat surprisingly, the Shapeless-less Scalaz solution is a little slower:

```
scala> Iterator.fill(10)(time(foos.reduce(_.|+|(_)(fooSemigroup)))._2).sum / 10
res6: Long = 311
```

But as I said, this is an extremely off-the-cuff approach to benchmarking, and you should run your own ([Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) is a great library for this).

In any case, yes, you're paying for the abstraction, but not that much, and it's often likely to be worth it.

Answer (score 13):

As discusssed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442440/unable-to-map-on-hlist), this is how you can solve the problem with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/), in a completely type-safe manner.

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import HList._
import HList._

scala> case class Foo(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int])
defined class Foo

scala> val a = Foo(Some(3), None)
a: Foo = Foo(Some(3),None)

scala> val b = Foo(Some(22), Some(1))
b: Foo = Foo(Some(22),Some(1))

scala> implicit val fooIso = HListIso(Foo.apply _, Foo.unapply _)
fooIso: shapeless.HListIso[Foo,shapeless.::[Option[Int],shapeless.::[Option[Int],shapeless.HNil]]] = shapeless.HListIso@11c5b77

scala> type O2[+A] = (Option[A], Option[A])
defined type alias O2

scala> object mapper extends (O2 ~> Option) {
     |   def apply[A](x: O2[A]): Option[A] = x._1.orElse(x._2)
     | }
defined module mapper

scala> fooIso.fromHList(fooIso.toHList(a).zip(fooIso.toHList(b)).map(mapper))
res13: Foo = Foo(Some(3),Some(1))
```

Comment: I've added a Shapeless example inspired by your answer in my answer—I hope you don't mind.