# Filter usage in shapeless, Scala

Tags: list, scala, filter, shapeless, heterogeneous

It is easy to filter `HList` in shapeless by type:

```
val hlist = 1 :: 2 :: "3" :: true :: false :: HNil
hlist.filter[Int]
```

But how can I make my custom type filter? I want smth like that: for example I got list of some functions:

```
def function1(s: String) = s.toInt
def function2(s: String) = s.toDouble
def function3(i: Int) = i.toDouble

val hflist = function1 _ :: function3 _ :: function2 _ :: HNil

hflist customFilter[String] //> function1 _ :: function2 _ :: HNil
```

So after usage of this filter, list of functions from type `String` to some other type will be constructed.

I had an idea to use map for this, but it was not successfull.

**EDITION**

More information about my comment:

I tried to test this ideas in map:

So if i got some lists (lets operate with `hlist` & `hflist`):

```
object allFunction extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T, M] =
    at[T => M](t => { 
      object grabStringFunc extends skip {
        implicit def stringFunc[A] = at[T => A](_ :: HNil)
      }

      println(hflist flatMap grabStringFunc) //> here we should see result, list of functions 
 })

 hlist map allFunction
 //> result of this should be smth like (types)
 //> shapeless.::[Int => Double,shapeless.HNil]]
 //> shapeless.::[Int => Double,shapeless.HNil]]
 //> shapeless.::[String => Int,shapeless.::[String => Double,shapeless.HNil]] 
 //> shapeless.HNil
 //> shapeless.HNil
```

Very interesting, why it compiles and works incorrect? As I think it is not works, cause object cant take type prameters in such a way...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a fold. First we need a polymorphic function that will add each item to the accumulator if it has the desired type (`String => A` for some `A`), and ignore it otherwise:

```
trait ignore extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[A, L <: HList] = at[A, L]((_, l) => l)
}

object keepStringFunc extends ignore {
  implicit def stringFunc[A, L <: HList] = at[String => A, L](_ :: _)
}
```

Now the following will give the result you want in both 1.2.4 and 2.0.0-M1:

```
val filtered = hflist.foldRight(HNil)(keepStringFunc)
```

You could also write your own type class on the model of `Filter`, `FilterAux` (or `Filter.Aux`), etc.—and doing so would be a good exercise if you're trying to get the hang of Shapeless—but `foldRight` is a lot simpler.

---

Update: actually, for what it's worth, there's a slightly more concise way to do this with `flatMap`:

```
trait skip extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[A] = at[A](_ => HNil)
}

object grabStringFunc extends skip {
  implicit def stringFunc[A] = at[String => A](_ :: HNil)
}

val filtered = hflist flatMap grabStringFunc
```

I personally find the `foldRight` version a little more obvious, but this one's also pretty elegant.

---

In response to your comment: you can make the solution a little more generic like this:

```
trait skip extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[A] = at[A](_ => HNil)
}

trait grabFuncFrom[T] extends skip {
  implicit def stringFunc[A] = at[T => A](_ :: HNil)
}

object grabStringFunc extends grabFuncFrom[String]

val filtered = hflist flatMap grabStringFunc
```

But you're still going to need that last step where you create the higher rank function as an object (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442871/334519) and Miles's comment there for some discussion of this issue).

Comment: omg, such a pretty decision; thx a lot! I'll try also to write my own `Filter` too. thx!

Comment: Hm, a little edition to my question, can we pass the prameter in function, i mean smth like `def stringFunc[A] = at[T => A](_ :: HNil)` ? why it is compiling, and why, in fact, it is not working? 
p.s. I am on my way writing own `Filter` :) thx!

Comment: y, for understanding shapeless. I wish I could upvote your answers lots of times. I added some information about my comment, what i tried. thx for your time! :)