# HList filtered by foldRight is not providing instances

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I'm using `libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.2.4"`

Currently i have model HList types like

```
sealed trait Section
case class Header(...) extends Section
case class Customer(...) extends Section
case class Supplier(...) extends Section
case class Tech(...) extends Section
type ContractView = Header :: (Customer :: Supplier :: HNil) :: Tech :: HNil
```

In my user code, i'd like to filter technical sections that are not supposed to view using `foldRight` as proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19894035/210905):

```
trait collectAllRF extends Poly2 {
  implicit def atAny[L <: HList, X] = at[X, L](_ :: _)
}

object collectVisRF extends collectAllRF {
  implicit def atInvis[L <: HList, S <: Section : InvisibleSection] = at[S, L]((_, l) => l)
}
```

For example there are defined:

```
trait InvisibleSection[S <: Section]
implicit object _techisInvisible extends InvisibleSection[Tech]
```

Fold is working correctly, but suddenly i could not use following `filter` or `map` on this object, so for example this code:

```
val filtered = view.foldRight(HNil)(collectVisRF)
view.filter[Header]
```

produces compile error:

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter partition:
>   shapeless.ops.hlist.Partition[shapeless.::[Header,shapeless.::[shapeless.::[Customer,shapeless.::[Supplier,shapeless.HNil]],shapeless.HNil.type]],Header]

while this

```
view.filter[Header]
```

and this

```
val h = view.select[Header] 
val l = view.select[Customer::Supplier::HNil]
val c = l.select[Customer]
val s = l.select[Supplier]
val manual = h :: (c :: s :: HNil) :: HNil
manual.filter[Header]
```

compiles ok

Lately i've found little `HNil.type` at end of `foldRight`'s result type and changed my filter definition to

```
view.foldRight(HNil.asInstanceOf[HNil])(collectVisRF)
```

And all worked properly

Is this an expected behaviour, and if yes why there is no some

```
val hNil: HNil = HNil
```

In the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your eventual fix is almost, but not quite, right. Rather than `asInstanceOf` you should use a type ascription,

```
view.foldRight(HNil: HNil)(collectVisRF)
```

Your question about why there is no definition of an hnil value typed as `HNil` rather than as `HNil.type` is a good one. shapeless is different from typical Scala libraries in that it makes heavy use of singleton types, `HNil.type` included, so the current situation isn't as obviously wrong as the corresponding situation in the Scala standard library where `None.type` and `Nil.type` are almost never desired.

Nevertheless the situation you describe in your question comes up more often than I would like, so it's clearly a real problem. I think it would be too confusing to have two hnil values, one with a more precise type than the other, so the question boils down to: how much existing stuff would break if `HNil` (the type) was inferred as the type of `HNil` (the value) rather than `HNil.type` as it is now.

Feel free to open a ticket in the shapeless issue tracker on Github to investigate this, and if you'd like to give it a try, please do :-)