# When is an empty HList not an HList?

Tags: scala, shapeless

While learning shapeless, I wonder, why this doesn't compile:

```
def someHList[H <: HList]: H = HNil
```

since the HNil object extends the HNil trait which extends HList?

What is the right way to define a method in a trait which returns some HList, which is only implemented in by the extending class?

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
trait Parent {
  def someHList[H <: HList]: H
}

object Child1 extends Parent {
  def someHList[H <: HList] = HNil
}

object Child2 extends Parent {
  def someHList[H <: HList] = 1 :: "two" :: HNil
}
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

To elaborate as I realize what I underspecified in my original question:

1.) It is desirable to not have to specify `H` explicitly in each implementing class, but rather let it be inferred (at the call site?).

2.) I'd like to use HNil as a default implementation in the parent trait which can optionally be overridden in subclasses. My example probably should have been:

```
trait Parent {
  def someHList[H <: HList]: H = HNil
}

object Child extends Parent {
  override def someHList[H <: HList] = 1 :: "two" :: HNill
}
```

Comment: This question's title is a bad pun/reference to this classic language puzzle, which is structurally similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_a_white_horse_is_not_a_horse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HNil` object is an `HList`. But it is not necessary `H`.

definition like

```
def someHList[H <: HList]: H = HNil
```

should be read as

> for any `type H`, subtype of `HList` there is a way to construct it's member and it will be `HNil`

which is obviously erroneous

Thing you are trying to do, as I feel, is rephrased version of it to

> there is a `type H`, subtype of `HList` and a way to construct it's member

If so you can use type member like this:

```
import shapeless._

trait Parent {
  type H <: HList
  def someHList: H
}

object Child1 extends Parent {
  type H = HNil
  def someHList: H = HNil
}

object Child2 extends Parent {
  type H = Int :: String :: HNil
  def someHList: H = 1 :: "two" :: HNil
}
```

#### Update

You can also refactor it a little bit to make some types infer automatically like

```
abstract class Parent[H <: HList](val someList: H)
object Child1 extends Parent(HNil: HNil)
object Child2 extends Parent(1 :: "two" :: HNil)
```

You may note that type for `HNil` is set manually, that is because type of `object HNil` is a `HNil.type`subtype of `HNil`, which can [lead the compiler wrong way sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583360/hlist-filtered-by-foldright-is-not-providing-instances)

Comment: Makes sense, and definitely the answer to my question. What I now realize I left out of my question is: Is there a way to infer `H` (at the call location?) without having to specify it explicitly in each implementing class?

Comment: Thanks! And +1 for highlighting the need for ascribing the type explicitly `HNil: HNil`

Answer (score 4):

If just use `HList` as a return type than everything works fine:

```
trait Parent {
  def someHList: HList
}

object Child1 extends Parent {
  def someHList = HNil
}

object Child2 extends Parent {
  def someHList = 1 :: "two" :: HNil
}
```

Or for the updated version of the question:

```
trait Parent {
  def someHList: HList = HNil
}

object Child2 extends Parent {
  override def someHList = 1 :: "two" :: HNil
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, but without any type parameters or type members, this invariant style cannot (as far as I know) be a part of the lemmas built with the Aux Pattern: https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide/blob/c4ecb5620b269d8080892eb69a85a9cc78d9778f/src/pages/ops/penultimate.md