# Encoding singleton objects as lazy vals

Tags: scala, singleton, semantics, lazy-evaluation

### Context

We are working on a static verifier for Scala programs (early work described in [this Master's thesis](http://www.pm.inf.ethz.ch/education/theses/student_docs/Bernhard_Brodowsky/MA_report)), and the current focus lies on verifying Scala features that involve lazy evaluation. We are mainly interested in the **semantics** (behaviour) of the features, not in other (nevertheless important) aspects such as comprehensibility or conciseness.

To simplify things, we - for the time being - ignore special roles that singleton objects could have. For example, that some are companion objects (which is probably orthogonal w.r.t. to their lazy nature), or that some are package objects.

### Properties of lazy vals and singleton objects

**Lazy vals**

Assume a lazy val

```
lazy val v = I
```

where `I` is the *initialiser* block, i.e., the code that determines the value of the lazy val. The initialiser block `I` is executed when the lazy val `v` is dereferenced for the first time.

**Singleton objects**

Assume a singleton object

```
object Foo {
  C1

  val v1 = I1
  var v2 = I2
  lazy val v3 = I3
  def m() {C2}
}
```

where `C1` is the code making up the constructor of object `Foo`, where `I1` to `I3` are again initialiser blocks, and where `C2` is the body of method `m`. When the object `Foo` is first used (dereferenced, or assigned to a variable/field), then `C1, I1` and `I2` are executed. `I3` is only executed when `Foo.v3` is dereferenced (since `v3` is a lazy val) and `C2` is executed whenever `m` is called.

### Question

Consider this version of `Foo`, where the singleton object has been encoded by a lazy val and an anonymous class:

```
// Should probably sit in a package object
lazy val Foo = new {
  C1

  val v1 = I1
  var v2 = I2
  lazy val v3 = I3
  def m() {C2}
}
```

Can anybody think of a reason for why the encoding of the singleton object `Foo` as a lazy val would show a different behaviour than the original singleton object? That is, are there (corner) cases where the encoded version would have a different semantics than the original code?

Comment: This is a good question—see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442871/334519) and the comment by Miles Sabin for one example of a case where there _is_ a difference (not sure about the _should be_, though).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! My interpretation of Miles' comment, though, is that the implementation of `Poly1` won't compile if the object were encoded as a lazy val, and that the reason is essentially due to name resolution. This was not quite the difference I had in mind, because code that is rejected by the compiler sort of obviously shows a different behaviour. Moreover, if the problem really is "just" due to name resolution, then it should be possible to resolve it in a way that does not affect the language semantics. But of course that's just a guess on my side ...

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one major semantic difference, which I explained herebelow. I think there are some corner cases in multi-threaded contexts, because objects are created during the *static initializer* of their class, and static initializers have a weird interaction with locks. But I am no JVM multi-thread expert, so I don't know the details.

Anyway, here is something that happens even in a single-threaded context (and that *is* used at least in the implementation of `Manifest`s, and maybe `ClassTag`s, in the current standard library).

Consider the following two objects:

```
object A {
  val other = B
}
object B {
  val other = A
}
```

This is valid Scala code, and accessing either `A.other` or `B.other` will correctly return the other one. This is because the "val" for `A` is initialized *right after the call to the super constructor*. Essentially, you could somehow translate the above object into this "low-level" code:

```
private var instanceA: AClass = null
def A(): AClass = {
  if (instanceA == null)
    new AClass
  instanceA
}
class AClass {
  def this() = {
    // reification of the constructor of A
    super()
    instanceA = this
    this.other = B()
  }
}
```

Of course, `B` is translated similarly. You can see that, at the time `B()` is called to initialize `A.other`, the global variable `instanceA` has already been initialized. Hence, when `B` is created and accesses `A()` to initialize `B.other`, the `def A()` will return immediately the right instance of `A`.

`lazy val`s do not have this early initialization, so encoding objects as simple `lazy val`s won't fly. Accessing either of the objects will "dead-lock" with the only threaded waiting for itself.

Comment: I don't see why super constructors should matter here.
I ran your object example (http://ideone.com/NSYJrv) and a corresponding lazy vals encoding (http://ideone.com/uQR1ys), both show the same behaviour: accessing `A`/`B` results in a `StackOverflowError` due to an infinite recursion.
The only difference that I observed is that the compiler cannot type `lazy val A` automatically (`recursive value other needs type`), which is not a problem with the object version, probably because objects don't declare types (`new {...}` implicitly does).
Btw, I think we met at Scala'13 in Montpellier.

Comment: In any case, thanks for the pointers to static initialisers - I'll try to find out whether or not they might make a difference.

Comment: Right, objects local to methods behave differently. My comment applied to top-level objects (or objects inside top-level objects, but not objects inside methods): http://ideone.com/xfsQI8 . The super constructor does not really matter, it is just where the instance is initialized.